# update twig template after jquery ajax get request

Tags: jquery, dom, get, request, twig

I have a js function passing on a get request to a php file to get db values for the selected record. The get request url reports correct in the js console and the sql is correct.

How do I  but I am not sure how to update the dom to refresh the twig template tags. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance, James

js:

```
function editCatalogue(id) {
   var dataString = 'id='+id;        
    $.get('catalogue_db.php', 
      dataString,
      function(returnData) {
        showDialog();

    });          
};
```

php:

```
if ( (isset($_GET)) && ($_GET['id'] !="") ) {

    require_once 'library/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';

    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('cache' => 'compilation_cache','debug' => true ));
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('catalogues.html');

    $catid = $_GET['id'];
    echo $catid;

    $sql = "SELECT
        catalogues.id,
        catalogues.title,
        catalogues.keywords,
        catalogues.code_bne,
        catalogues.description
        FROM
        catalogues
        WHERE
        catalogues.id = {catid}
        LIMIT 1 ";

    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {

        echo $template->render(array( 
            'title' => $row['title'],
            'code_bne' => $row['code_bne'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
            'keywords' => $row['keywords']
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Twig template has already been rendered "Pre-process" on the server. If you're trying to update the DOM, just return JSON data from your GET request and reset the HTML container element with that.

If you're trying to permanently update the Twig template, you're gonna have to update it within a database record. Of course that'd mean storing your template in a database table. Or write to the file directly from PHP.

Comment: I have amended this to produce a json result and it echoed out as {"id":"1916","title":"test1","keywords":"abc, def, ghi, klmn","description":"abcdefg"} but jquery is receiving the array with null values. obj = jQuery.parseJSON(returnData); alert(obj.title);